# Project Reactor: Sum two Mono<Integer> without blocking

Tags: project-reactor, nonblocking, reactor

Suppose that we have:

`Mono<Integer> int1 = Mono.just(1)` and `Mono<Integer> int2 = Mono.just(10)`. I would like get the sum of these two integer without blocking.

In the blocking way I would do this:
`Mono<Integer> result = Mono.just(int1.block() + int2.block())`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `zip`:

```
Mono<Integer> int1 = Mono.just(1); //or any other mono, including lazy one
Mono<Integer> int2 = Mono.just(10); //same


Mono<Integer> sum = Mono.zip(
    int1, int2,
    //zip defaults to producing a Tuple2
    //but for the 2 args version you can provide a BiFunction
    (a, b) -> a + b
);

//if you want to verify, eg. in a test:
StepVerifier.create(sum)
    .expectNext(11)
    .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: in the code  you used `just` instead of `zip` by accident